# Tshark : child process exited abnormally

Tags: linux, tshark

When we execute the following command, I am getting the following error even though i have the corresponding value in the **Tshark** capture.

```
% tshark -r /root/capture.enc -R "icmpv6.option.type == 3"
tshark: Neither "icmpv6.option.type" nor "3" are field or protocol names. child process exited abnormally
%
```

Can anyone please help me ?

## This is the packet (Only ICMPv6 portion)

> ICMPv6 Option (Prefix information : 2001:abcd:2:ffff::/64) 
>       Type: Prefix information (3)
>       Length: 4 (32 bytes)
>       Prefix Length: 64

Answer (score 0):

> tshark: Neither "icmpv6.option.type" nor "3" are field or protocol names

TShark is correct when it says that.  "icmpv6.opt.type", however, *is* a field name, so you want

```
tshark -r /root/capture.enc -R "icmpv6.opt.type == 3"
```

"child process exited abnormally" indicates a bug - in that case, TShark should just report the incorrect read filter.  Please report the "child process exited abnormally" error as a bug on [the Wireshark Bugzilla](http://bugs.wireshark.org/).